# How to get the last one data from each collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I want to get only one latest data sorted by `created_at` from each collection,

this is my code now :

```
$getDevice = Devices::where('id_project', $id_project)
                          ->where('id_room', $id_room)
                          ->get()
                          ->groupBy(function($item){
                              return $item->mac_address;
                          });

 dd($getDevice);
```

the output:

[image: output]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot order data in group for mysql, so you can do it like this:

#### FOR MYSQL WAY:

---

AUTO INCREMENT ID:

The latest data from each collection means the max id in each collection.

So you can find all the `max id` in each group, and use subquery to get all these records:

```php
$getDevice = Devices::whereIn('id', function($q) use ($id_project, $id_room) {
                          $q->from('devices')
                            ->where('id_project', $id_project)
                            ->where('id_room', $id_room)
                            ->groupBy('mac_address')
                            ->selectRaw('MAX(id) AS id');
                      })->get();
```

UUID:

Because uuid is a unordered string, you can join by `mac_address` and  `max created_at`. And group by mac_address again, so it will get the latest data

```php
$deviceQuery = Devices::where('id_project', $id_project)
                      ->where('id_room', $id_room)
                      ->groupBy('mac_address')
                      ->select('mac_address', 'MAX(created_at) AS created_at');


$getDevice = Devices::joinSub($deviceQuery, 'dev', function($join) {
                          $join->on('dev.mac_address', '=', 'devices.mac_address')
                               ->whereColumn('dev.created_at', 'devices.created_at');
                      })->groupBy('mac_address')
                        ->get();
```

#### For Collection way:

---

Collection will be more readable, however, it need to takes the data out from DB, and then filter to get the last data in group.

```php
$getDevice = Devices::where('id_project', $id_project)
                          ->where('id_room', $id_room)
                          ->get()
                          ->groupBy('mac_address')
                          ->map(function($items) {
                              return $items->sortByDesc('mac_address')->first();
                          })->values();
```

Comment: can i change `->selectRaw('MAX(id) AS id'); ` with created_at time ?
because my id  is UUID

i try change `->selectRaw('MAX(created_at) AS created_at');`   showing null []

Comment: Thank you, it's work like charm,
i'm use Collection way, and there a bit correction, im change `sortByDesc('mac_address')` to `sortByDesc('created_at')`

Answer (score 0):

Try $model->orderBy('column', 'desc')->first();

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devices::latest()->first();
So you can build query with this example:

```
Devices::where('id_project', $id_project)
          ->where('id_room', $id_room)
          ->latest()->first();
```